# Create an .avi file from a list of bitmap images

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, screenshot, avi

I am currently trying to make a screen recorder.
I made list of bitmap images and want to put them in an .avi file.
Is there anyway to do that in C#?

note: i'm a novice, so keep things simple

Comment: What code do you have currently ? can you show us where you are having the issue..?

Comment: Agreed, the more information you can provide, the better.  (Do note that saving each frame as a bitmap will cause your end result to have a very large file size.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site which has downloadable examples as well: [A Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library)

Answer (score 2):

Try [SharpAvi](http://sharpavi.codeplex.com) library. Its sources include a sample screen recording application.