# C# WinForms - Create a video from images

Tags: c#, winforms, video, bitmap

I would like to know a way to create a video (format doesn't matter) out of images from the hard drive. I've been searching for a while and here are the solutions I've tried:

- `AForge.Video.ffmpeg`: causes exceptions while loading dependencies even though everything is in place
- `Bytescout image to video SDK`: this one actually works but the problem is that the demo version leaves water mark on the video (the full version costs a ton)

Comment: This is a very good question - sadly it can't have a definitive answer. You are requesting a tool suggestion and that kind of questions are not welcome - among other things - because this questions are open ended.

Comment: I am not asking for a tool!!!! All I want is some help to achieve this  with or without a third party library!!!!

Comment: Library / Tool, where do you draw the line? Anyway, the same applies: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." taken from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you could settle on a video format and a particular library this could be easier to adress.

Comment: Anyhow, some of the related questions may be useful, for instance  [Working way to make video from images in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c-sharp?rq=1) and [Create an .avi file from a list of bitmap images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802778/create-an-avi-file-from-a-list-of-bitmap-images?rq=1) may give some clues.